# Imported CSV point data layer invisible over the raster map layer, though each layer shows good separately "zoom to content"

Tags: qgis, csv, overlay

I am trying to import CSV file (comma delimited text) and get no reported errors but there are no points data visible overlays over raster data map
 1. QGIS 3.6
 2. the point data layer over raster map layer. 
 3. I can zoom to extent for each layer properly, each visible separately.
 4. Each layer data is set the same datum GDA94 EPSG 4283
 5. QGIS

I have tried to find an answer here but none seem to fit my problem. 
[image][image][image]

Comment: Are you sure your raster imagery is in EPSG 4283? In the layer name we see "EPSG28356_Date...", looks like your image might be projected in MGA Zone 51, which is a different crs, same datum (GDA94) but different coordinate system (4283 is geographic, and 28356 is projected). Is On the fly reprojection enabled in the project options?

Comment: Dear FS 
EPSG:28356
GDA94 / MGA zone 56 (Google it)

WGS84 Bounds: 150.0000, -37.8000, 156.0000, -21.7000
Projected
Bounds: 189586.6272, 5812134.5296, 810413.3728, 7597371.5494
Scope: Large and medium scale topographic mapping and engineering survey.
Last Revised: June 2, 1995
Area: Australia - 150°E to 156°E

Comment: Thanks FS, Yes, done, I changed the raster layer CRS to EPSG 28356 (Nearmap default GDA94/MGA zone 56). All done. Thanks.